# Avoid custom icon in flutter_local_notifications

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-local-notification

I have set up flutter_local_notifications to provide reminders in my app.  However, I am getting stuck with specifying the app icon for android.  For normal notifications the colour of the notification icon reacts to the colour of the background on which it is painted (a dark grey colour if the background is light, a white colour if the background is dark).  However, with flutter_local_notifications it seems necessary to specify the app icon when initialising the notification:

```
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
```

(or using @mipmap/ic_launcher if you prefer).  However, this means that the icon is always shown with a constant colour, irrespective of the background colour at the time.  Is there a way to get the other behaviour, where the OS chooses the colour of the icon depending on the current context?

Thanks